# How do I permit specific users SSH access by softlayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to add a normal user(such as 'vcap') ssh key to virtual guest while provisioning because of the security issue.

Could I send a request to SoftLayer endpoint to add non-root sshkey?

Comment: when you are ordening a virtual guest using the Control Portal (UI) there is a section to configure the SSH keys, are you talking about how to configure that with the API?

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza Yes.

Answer (score 0):

To create SSH while provisioning you can see documentation:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_virtual_guest/createobject

[image]

however the SSH is set for the root user, if you want to set it to another user you first need to create the user in the machine and then set his ssh key, you can try an script for that you just need to set the property postInstallScriptUri with the URL where your scritp is stored

[image]

You can see this documentation about the post install script:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/jarteche/getting-started-user-data-and-post-provisioning-scripts

You just need to create the proper script to work in your machine.